# Form not submitting html

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get an simple email form to work.
It is not responding to my submit button.
What did I do wrong or is there something I left out?

```
                            <?php
                                    if($error == 'ja')
                                    {
                                        // maak random getallen voor anti spam
                                        $spam_1 = rand(1,10);
                                        $spam_2 = rand(1,10);
                                        $spam = 'Anti spam beveiliging, wat is het antwoord op deze som: '.$spam_1.' + '.$spam_2.' =';
                                        ?>

                                        <form method="post" action="?">
                                            <div class="row uniform 50%">
                                                <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" <?php if($error_name == 'ja') {echo 'style="border:1px solid #E41C2E"';} ?> /></div>
                                                <div class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall)"><input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" <?php if($error_email == 'ja') {echo 'style="border:1px solid #E41C2E"';} ?> /></div>
                                                <div class="12u$"><textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" rows="4" <?php if($error_message == 'ja') {echo 'style="border:1px solid #E41C2E"';} ?> ></textarea></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                        <ul class="actions">
                                            <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" /></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    </form>
                                    <?php
                                }

                                    ?>
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    echo 'working';
}
```

[image]

Comment: Replace  `action="?"` to `action="#"`

Comment: Same result > no result

Comment: You are not wrapped `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    echo 'working';
}` with `<?php ?>`

Comment: Wrap it like this : `<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    echo 'working';
} ?>`

Comment: Also take your **submit** to Form's scope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include your submit field **within** the form.

Comment: Do or do not, there is no try.

Comment: I see! Sorry just getting used used to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button it outside the form. Please try this:

```
<form method="post" action="?">
    <div class="row uniform 50%">
        <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" <?php if($error_name == 'ja') {echo 'style="border:1px solid #E41C2E"';} ?> /></div>
        <div class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall)"><input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" <?php if($error_email == 'ja') {echo 'style="border:1px solid #E41C2E"';} ?> /></div>
        <div class="12u$"><textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" rows="4" <?php if($error_message == 'ja') {echo 'style="border:1px solid #E41C2E"';} ?> ></textarea></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="actions">
        <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" /></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```